# How to add html codes in email?

Tags: php, html, email

I have created a script that sends email automatically! My  mail message is included in the following variable

```
$message
```

But when i include a html code like  or something else it is not shown properly in my mail!

Comment: "not shown properly in my mail" is way too vague. We need specifics.

Comment: You should use well known library for emailing. PHPMailer is very stable and fully featured module. It's open source and also has LITE edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$subject = "Subject here";
$message = "email message here";

$sendMail = mail("info@domain.com", "$subject", "$message", "$headers" );
```

Comment: Unless you have good reason not to, should use UTF-8 rather than iso-8859-1 as the charset.

Comment: Yeah, if you're doing multilingual, definitely UTF-8.

Comment: no dude i want to include a html code in that $message one! Please help me!

Comment: @divya-mamgai That's the whole point. The HTML will not work unless you set the headers to render the e-mail as HTML, which is what he just detailed.

Comment: @divya-mamgai No problem, everyone has to start at some time. Let us know if you need anymore help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the mail command make sure you
Are setting the right headers eg

$headers  = "From: $from\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);