# How do I send HTML formatted mail using PHP?

Tags: php, email, formatting

Trying to send a html email via mail(), however gmail just displays the email as plain text, no mark up, eg:

```
mail("blah@blah.com", "subject", "<i>Italic Text</i>");
```

just appears as

```
<i>Italic Text</i>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use HTML formatting in email sent from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971322/use-html-formatting-in-email-sent-from-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php mail: how to send html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897215/php-mail-how-to-send-html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include html in email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916477/include-html-in-email)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add html codes in email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055757/how-to-add-html-codes-in-email)

Comment: You can't use HTML in the message subject.

Comment: sorry, my apologies, didn't notice I skipped the subject parameter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to specify that the contents of the mail is HTML:

```
mail("blah@blah.com", "subject", "<i>Italic Text</i>", "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
```

Answer (score 7):

See example 4 on this page:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a properly formed html doc:

```
$msg = "<html><head></head><body><i>Italic Text</i></body></html>";
```

Edit:

And send headers:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail("blah@blah.com", $msg, $headers);
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you must set the `content-type` to `text/html` in your headers.

Something like the string `"Content-type:text/html"`

Where to "insert" this header? Take a look at the function reference at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

In order for it to be properly interpreted, you must also set the headers in the email, especially:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

You should also set the other usual headers. The message can finally be sent like this:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

You should refer to the [php manual mail page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for more information.